# Перенос текста из одного текстового поля во второе текстовое поле при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Только начал учить pyqt, решил попробовать сделать мини мессенджер.

Столкнулся с проблемой переноса текста. Надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку текст из `lineEdit` переносился в `plainTextEdit`, а с `lineEdit` удалялся.

Вот код, где должна быть функция:

```
import sys
from messenger import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.build_handlers

#начало функции

def build_handlers(self):
     self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)

def on_button_click(self, event):
    message = self.lineEdit.text()
    self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(message)
 
#конец функции 

def main():
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = ExampleApp()
window.show()
app.exec_()

if __name__=="__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from messenger import Ui_MainWindow


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

#        self.build_handlers
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)    # + .ui

    def on_button_click(self):
        message = self.ui.lineEdit.text()                           # + .ui
        self.ui.lineEdit.clear()                                    # +++
        self.ui.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(message)              # + .ui


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

---

**messenger.py**

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(356, 298)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(254, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 356, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

---

**Update**

или так:

мне лично второй вариант больше нравится.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from messenger import Ui_MainWindow


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):          # +  Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)    

    def on_button_click(self):
        message = self.lineEdit.text()                          
        self.lineEdit.clear()                                     # +++
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(message)            


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

---

**Update 2**

> Еще хотелось бы уточнить, можно ли сделать чтоб при нажатии enter нажималась кнопка?

добавьте в конструктор (метод **init**) self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.on_button_click). Читать здесь doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished .

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from messenger import Ui_MainWindow


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):          # +  Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click) 
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.on_button_click)    # <<---<       

    def on_button_click(self):
        message = self.lineEdit.text()                          
        self.lineEdit.clear()                                     # +++
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(message)            


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Напишите что вам не понятно, я прокомментирую.

Comment: @imapw_  добавьте в конструктор (`метод __init__`) `self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.on_button_click)`. Читать здесь 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished .   Если мои ответы решили вашу проблему, не забудьте отметить ответ как правильный.

Comment: @imapw_  я добавил ответ на ваш вопрос в `Update 2`